# Можно ли в Go сделать поле в структуре кастомного типа?

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Например:

1. Есть структура с полем типа int:

```
type Channel struct {
    Chan  int `json:"chan"`
}
```

2. Есть структура с полем типа string:

```
type Channel struct {
    Chan  string `json:"chan"`
}
```

Как можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
type Channel struct {
    Chan  CustomType `json:"chan"`
}
```

Какие в принципе есть варианты такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct {
    data interface{}
}

func Test2(data interface{}) {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(data).Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        fmt.Println("строка")
    case reflect.Int:
        fmt.Println("инт")
    }
}

func main() {
    str := "Hello world"
    number := 34
    test := Test{}
    test.data = str
    Test2(test.data)
    test.data = number
    Test2(test.data)
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Ayaz, да, это подходит. Спасибо, за ваше решение.

Answer (score 0):

Обьявление типа UserId. Тип UserId = int64

```
type UserId int64
```

Обьявление типа UserInfo.

```
type UserInfo struct {
    id UserId
    name string
    password string
}
```

Обьявление типа UsersInfo.

```
type UsersInfo struct {
    users []UserInfo
    createdAt time.Time
}
```

Comment: Наверно некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Имелось ввиду, что есть тип, который может иметь над собой базовый тип как int так и тип string. 
Например, изначально данные в Mongo хранились в одном формате (string), а после обновления приложения тип поменялся на int.
Теперь возникает ситуация, что сейчас данные в монгу летят с типом int. Но у клиента лежат и старые данные, тип у которых string. 
В связи с этим вопрос, как лучше обработать такую ситуацию.